# View setBackgroundColor not working android

Tags: android

I have a problem with setting background color of a view (Note: all elements are View)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    final Context context = this;

    //Original Colors (Hardcodeded for nice looks)
    int r1c = Color.parseColor("#ff00eeff");
    int r2c = Color.parseColor("#ff21ff2e");

    //Final Colors Random
    int r1f = randomColor();
    int r2f = randomColor();

    //Get int for progress
    int progress = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final View r1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.r1);
        final View r2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.r2);

        final SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        bar.setProgress(0);
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                progress = bar.getProgress();
                updateColors(r1,r1c,r1f);
                updateColors(r2,r2c,r2f);

                //updateColors(r1,r1c,r1f); Grey in this case TODO automatic
            }

        });
    }

    public void updateColors(View v, int ogcolor, int fcolor) {
        ArgbEvaluator getColorAtPos = new ArgbEvaluator();

        float percent = (float) progress / 100; //Does this return float expected between 0.0 and 1.0 ???? Im new to java so not sure
        v.setBackgroundColor((Integer) getColorAtPos.evaluate(percent, ogcolor, fcolor));
        v.invalidate();
    }

    int randomColor() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = (int) rand.nextInt(255);
        int g = (int) rand.nextInt(255);
        int b = (int) rand.nextInt(255);
        int color = Color.argb(255,r, g, b);
        return color;
    }

}
```

I have described most in comments in code, but once more, when I move `seekBar`, `onProgressChanged` is called successfully, also `updatecolors` is called, yet I can't see the color changing on activity.

Comment: tried refreshing the view? `view.requestLayout()`

Comment: ok got it , GetProgress() was not working as expected , so value of process was always 0  , (int progress was defined at start of onCreate and  it is also in args of onProgressChanged so there was conflict ,but i wonder why AS did not warn me about same var name twice

Comment: Can you put an answer in the answer box provided and then accept  it? This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it , GetProgress() was not working as expected , so value of process was always 0 , (int progress was defined at start of onCreate and it is also in args of onProgressChanged so there was conflict ,but i wonder why AS did not warn me about same var name twice